# Showing previously checked records marked 'inactive' in edit form with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails convention uses the same `_form.html.erb` form for both creating a `new` record, and for `editing` an existing record.  This is causing an issue with  an `f.collection_check_boxes` section in my form because I am attempting to distinguish between `active` and `inactive` selections.

- For creating a new record, I want to display only those checkbox selections that have the `active` attribute marked as: `true`.
- Editing an existing record is different.  Like for new records, I want to display all checkbox selections whose `active` attribute is marked as `true`.  But I also want to show any already existing checked selections, even if the `active` attribute is marked as `false`.

Here is a tangible example.  I have `companies`, `languages`, and `companies_languages`.  The `companies_languages` table is a rich join table, representing language interpreters that this company has on staff.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :companies_languages, "What Language Translators are on Staff?" %><br>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes("language_ids", Language.active, :id, :name ) do |language| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <%= language.check_box(class: "check_box") %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-11">
            <%= language.object.name %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works great when creating a `new` company and choosing from all `active` languages in order to specify the language interpreters the company has on staff.

However, it does not work great for `editing` a company.  Any languages this company has interpreters for whose `active` attribute is marked `false` is simply not shown.  This makes it not possible for the user to remove those `inactive` interpreters, or to see them at all in the `edit` form.

Any tips for solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to some help:

```
 ...

 <%= f.collection_check_boxes("language_ids", Language.active + @company.languages.inactive, :id, :name ) do |language| %>

 ...
```

This works for the `@agency` that is new because it doesn't have any `languages.inactive`.  It also works for `@agency` when we `edit` it because it grabs all the `active` agencies, but also shows any `inactive` languages that already exist.